# How to use Office 365 SDK with Gradle?

Tags: java, maven, outlook

I want to do some testing with [this SDK provided by Microsoft](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java). Clicking the download button on that page tells me to import it with gradle using the following dependency:

```
compile 'com.microsoft.services:graph-services-java:0.2.5'
```

however I get a build error telling me:

```
Could not find com.microsoft.services:graph-services-java:0.2.5.
Searched in the following locations:
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/services/graph-services-java/0.2.5/graph-services-java-0.2.5.pom
  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/services/graph-services-java/0.2.5/graph-services-java-0.2.5.jar
```

Looking at the directory listings, this is as far as I get before the path breaks:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/microsoft/

As you can see there's no "services" directory. Is the original URL wrong? Is gradle set up to look in the wrong place? How do I fix this? Note I am able to import their EWS API in a similar manner just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bintray JCenter repo:

https://bintray.com/package/files/msopentech/Maven/Office-365-SDK-for-Java?order=asc&sort=name&basePath=com%2Fmicrosoft%2Fservices%2Fgraph-services-java%2F0.2.5&tab=files

For some reason MS put it only there.

Btw. this lib is outdated. I had to customize it by myself to make it work with current Graph API. This is not officially supported SDK I guess, see: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/code-samples-and-sdks